# Laravel unit testing calling a Route from a Test with authentication

Tags: php, api, unit-testing, laravel

I'm testing my api. Before calling a route I log in user to application.
Problem is that after authentication user's id is not assigned to `Auth::id()` within route call.

Here is the scenario:

**Test method:**

```
public function testApiGetOrder()
{
    var_dump($this->user);  // first dump
    Auth::login($this->user); // Can't use $this->be($this->user) here, it would not help anyway...
    var_dump(Auth::id());  // second dump

    $response = $this->call('GET', '/order/' . $this->order->getKey());

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertJson($response->getContent());
    $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString($this->order->toJson(), $response->getContent());
}
```

**OrderController's method:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    var_dump(Auth::id());  // third dump
    var_dump(Auth::user()->getKey());   // fourth dump

    // Calling model's logic here
}
```

***Output of of testApiGetOrder:***

First dump:  `object(User)`
Second dump: `int(1)`
Third dump:  `NULL`
Fourth dump: `int(1)`

Why the value of user's id is not assigned to `Auth::id()` ?

Comment: Because you still haven't' login in third dump?

Comment: try to switch the order of third and fourth dump. If my suspicion is correct I'll write an expanded answer on why this is occuring.

Comment: Result is as I would excpect. Third dump: int(1), Fourth dump: NULL. 
Third dump = var_dump(Auth::user()->getKey()) now. 
Fourth dump = var_dump(Auth::id()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not talking about the same instance of Auth.

In your test you got an instance of Auth library where you logged in hence you get data back. 
When you do a call the controller has it's own instance of auth (running within Laravel framework)

Cleaner way to create your test is to use mock of Auth library. It is tested by Laravel and during a unit test you want to test the smallest piece of code.

```
public function testApiGetOrder()
{
    Auth::shouldReceive('id')->with($this->user->getKey())
                             ->once()->andReturn($this->user);

    Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($this->user);

    $response = $this->call('GET', '/order/' . $this->order->getKey());

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertJson($response->getContent());
    $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString($this->order->toJson(), $response->getContent());
}
```

Comment: Problem is that Auth::id() is not called directly in controller's method. I use query scope to filter orders by user's id from database. The scope is called from model's method so I think Mockery does not catch any Auth::id() call...?
I get Mockery NoMatchingExpectationException after mocking Auth... Is here a way how to get trough this?

Comment: Mock the model, your not testing your model in your controller. You need to verify that your controller calls the required methods on your model. nothing more.